# Bash script to type into console 'exit' then ENTER key

Tags: linux, bash, console

I have never used linux, now I am in my senior year as an ECE student at Oregon State and I must learn to use it at an accelerated pace. I do not know enough terminology to begin the search for what I need.
I am compiling some simulations on the university engineering server. The first step requires me to use dc_shell. Once I have completed that portion the rest of my Bash script just hangs waiting on an input into the console 'exit' followed by a return key. Please find the image below of my script with the location of the needed code in capitol letters.
Thanks in advance--

[My first bash script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGHFF.png)

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO. As per my understanding you want to get user input in script ?  You can used `read` function for that. and CLI is awesome please don't hate it :{

Comment: Hi, welcome. Most people have not enough time to read through big paragraphs, I would recommend to be briefer. As said before, I also would recommend to copy & paste code. I would try to use redirection of stdin on Linux / *nix OSs, e.g. `dc_shell-xg-t < scriptfile`